# JPA: update or delete on table violates foreign key constraint

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data

I have a bankData entity with relation manyToOne with the IbanEntity. When i delete a bankData i get the below error.

I tried with `@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)` but is stay the same problem.

> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: update or delete
> on table "iban_entity" violates foreign key constraint
> "fk45b3uuwudhhbbko8v3r4c0pl5" on table "bank_data_entity"   Détail :
> Key (iban, rib)=(FR7630001007941234567890185, 30001007941234567890185)
> is still referenced from table "bank_data_entity".

```
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumns(value = { @JoinColumn(name = "fk_rib", referencedColumnName = "rib"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "fk_iban", referencedColumnName = "iban") })
private IbanEntity ibanEntity;

@Entity
@IdClass(IbanKey.class)
public class IbanEntity implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Id
  private String rib;

  @Id
  private String iban;

  public String getRib() {
      return rib;
  }

  public IbanEntity rib(String rib) {
      this.rib = rib;
      return this;
  }

  public String getIban() {
      return iban;
  }

  public IbanEntity iban(String iban) {
      this.iban = iban;
      return this;
  } 

}
```

Comment: I don't see any `OnDeleteAction.CASCADE` on your code... I would suggest you to set up the delete policy on the DBMS

Comment: Yea, that's not how you do that.